# List items get duplicated in React Native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, firebase, react-native

I have the following code sequence where some calendar data is checked with scheduling data.
The problem is that if there are 2 or more appointments, I get the rest duplicated, tripled. How can I change?

[image]

```js
{ programari.map(val=>{

  if(val.date==selectedDate){
    if(val.hour==hour){
      return(
        <RadioButton.Item label={hour} value={hour} disabled={true} style={{backgroundColor:'red',opacity:0.4}} />
      )  
    }        
    else return <RadioButton.Item label={hour} value={hour} disabled={false} style={{backgroundColor:'green',opacity:0.4}} />
  }

})}
```

Comment: Seems you've not added curly braces around your else return statement, not sure if how you've got it in there would work

Comment: As React must be warning you, you should add a `key` prop with a unique value (not an array index) for each child of the map. e.g. `<ReactButton.Item key={hour} ...` (if the list isn't multi-day and hour is unique).

Comment: There are several appointments, and each appointment is compared to the calendar days.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the contents of programari? is you have duplicates in this list you will need to erase the duplicates. It is easy to avoid duplicates if somehow you use a set and from the set you create programari. On the other hand, shouldn't you consider minutes, too? Dominic also suggested the use of a Key and this is true. As key, you can use the index of the element in programari concatenated with something else to get a unique value.